# Unit Test jquery click event using jest

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jestjs, click, enzyme

I have a jquery written for the click event and want to test it using jest.

```
$(document).click(event => {
    if ($(event.target).is($('.elemet1'))) {
        function1();
    }
    if ($(event.target).is($('.elemet2'))) {
        function2();
    }
});
```

I want to test that when event.target is element1 then function1 is called but if event.target is element2 then function2 is called.

what I am trying to do it 
`$(document).click();`
but in this event.target is coming as undefined. I am not able to find a way to make conditions true.
How to pass event when we are clicking.

Comment: Where are you defining `element1` and `element2`, and what are their values?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have edited my post. element1 and element2 are class names of 2 different elements.

Comment: In that case your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/p0wfu5z1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know it is working fine. But I want to write the test case for this using jest.